# Find an integral for the area of the surface generated by revolving the curve $y=sin(x)$ between $0 \le x \le \pi$, about the x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, surfaces

So here is my problem:

Find an integral for the area of the surface generated by revolving the curve $y=sin(x)$ between $0 \le x \le \pi$, about the x-axis

Just thinking about the problem I feel like I would just do the following:

$$2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

But I'm not sure if this is the way to go about doing this.  Any hints?

Comment: Write $\sin$ using `\sin` instead of `sin` and write $\mathrm dx$ using `\mathrm{d}x` instead of `dx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface area is found by the formula
$$A = 2\pi\int\rho\, ds,$$
where $\rho$ is the radius of rotation and $ds$ is the element of arc-length.
You have
$$A = 2\pi \int_0^\pi \sin(x)\sqrt{1 + \cos^2(x)}\, dx$$
Can you integrate this?

Comment: If the OP can't,he or she should consider another line of study because that integrand's about as easy as it gets from here.........lol